# Using ViewData in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a ViewData in an ASP.Net Controller like this:

```
var elements = db.Requests.GroupBy(user => user.submitUser)
                   .Select(slt => new { UsersCount = slt.Key, CountReq = slt.Count() });
```

this will have for example

```
UsersCount      Count

user1           3

user2           3

user3           3
```

Then in Javascript I want to create an array with UsersCount and Count, for example:

```
var arrayUsers = ViewData.UsersCount;
var arrayCounter = ViewData.CountReq;
```

I already tried several solutions and I can't do it. What's the best solution?

CONTROLLER:

```
 public ActionResult Statistics()
        {
            var elements = db.Requests.GroupBy(user => user.submitUser)
                            .Select(slt => new { UsersCount = slt.Key, CountReq = slt.Count() });


            ViewData["usersCounter"] = elements;

            return View();
        }
```

Javascript in VIEW

```
<script>
    var check = @ViewData["usersCounter"]**;**error

....

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: try dis var check = '@ViewData["usersCounter"]';

Answer (score 1):

To use ViewData in a javascript tag just prefix ViewData with the @ symbol

```
var check = @ViewData["array"]
```

In your controller

```
ViewData["array"] = elements;
```

Why not just set the variable to your model since it looks like you're setting it to that

```
var check = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Then you can do whatever

```
var blur = check.UserName
```

Comment: when i do that i get a "syntax error" on the ; after that

Comment: Can you post more code from your controller, and javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
@ViewData["usersCounter"]
```

will effectively do this:

```
@ViewData["usersCounter"].ToString()
```

You're setting your viewdata to the result of a select, so the `.ToString` wil output the generic generic type name directly to the output.

Simply check the source code of the rendered page to see what is being rendered.

Also, specify the 'error' that you get.

If you only change your code to

```
var check = '@ViewData["array"]'
```

(as per other answers) then 'check' will not contain the list, only the list.tostring()

If you want to copy the whole list into a js variable, you'll need to serialise it first, eg, something like (with JSON nuget package installed):

```
var check = @(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewData["array"]));
```

To note: many people will recommend that you use a ViewModel rather than ViewData as it's strongly typed as generally easier to work with / maintain.

However, is there as reason you need/want this in javascript?  The GroupBy and Select, even after converting to js aren't really js, and are better suited for working with c# or `@{}` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Andre have you tried

```
var check = '@ViewData["array"]'
```